# Return a list of Max values

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Myfile = open('GG.txt') 
c = [i[:] for i in Myfile] 

def cole():
    x = 0

    for line in c:
        a = line.strip().split(' ') 
        for m in a:

            if(int(m) > x):
                x = int(m)

    for line in c:
        if str(x) in line:
            return ('[' + line.strip() + ']') 

print(cole())
```

Here is my code that takes a 2D list and find the max value in each column, and returns a list containing the max values.

Here's the output:

[image]

My question is how can I make it so it it separated by commas?

So like, 
Expected output:

[62, 998, 4, 25, 936, 126, 553, 634, 316, 760, 197, 181, 427, 175, 259, 210]

Comment: Return `line.split(' ')`, not a string.

Comment: Why are you using `i[:]` when reading from the file?

Comment: wanna remove the \n chars

Comment: return `line.strip().split(' ')`

Comment: Why don't you strip and split the lines when you're creating `c`, so you don't have to do it again in both loops.

Comment: return line.strip().split(' ') output strings(['62','998','4'.....]. I want it to be int

Comment: You can simply edit this line `return ('[' + line.strip() + ']')` to `return ('[' + line.strip().replace(' ', ', ' + ']')`. Just replace a space with a comma and a space ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're creating the `c` list, call `strip`, `split`, and `int`, so you don't have to do that repeatedly in the other loops.

You can also save the line containing the max value in a variable at the same time as you update the max value, so you don't need a second loop.

There's no need to use both `strip()` and `split()`. If you omit the argument to `split()`, it splits on any whitespace, so the newlines will be ignored.

```
Myfile = open('GG.txt') 
allLines = [[int(num) for num in line.split()] for line in Myfile]

def cole(c):
    x = 0
    bigLine = []
    for line in c:
        for m in line:
            if (m > x):
                x = m
                bigLine = line
    return bigLine

print(cole(allLines))
```